# System.NullReferenceException when constructing object in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I just completed the task of migrating a large solution from .NET 3.5 to 4.0.  Pretty straight forward and application runs without incident.  However, when I try to open one of the child windows, I get the following exception:

> Type : System.NullReferenceException,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Message : Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object. Source :
>   WindowsBase Help link :  Data :
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite : System.String
>   AntiFormat(System.String) Stack Trace
>   :    at
>   MS.Internal.AvTrace.AntiFormat(String
>   s)    at
>   MS.Internal.AvTraceBuilder.AppendFormat(String
>   message, String arg1, String arg2)
>   at
>   MS.Internal.TraceData.DescribeSourceObject(AvTraceBuilder
>   traceBuilder, Object o)    at
>   MS.Internal.TraceData.DescribeTarget(AvTraceBuilder
>   traceBuilder, DependencyObject
>   targetElement, DependencyProperty
>   targetProperty)    at
>   MS.Internal.TraceData.Describe(AvTraceBuilder
>   traceBuilder, Object o)    at
>   MS.Internal.TraceData.OnTrace(AvTraceBuilder
>   traceBuilder, Object[] parameters,
>   Int32 start)    at
>   MS.Internal.AvTrace.Trace(TraceEventType
>   type, Int32 eventId, String message,
>   String[] labels, Object[] parameters) 
>   at
>   MS.Internal.TraceData.Trace(TraceEventType
>   type, AvTraceDetails traceDetails,
>   Object p1)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.ReportNoInfoError(Int32
>   k, Object parent)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.ReplaceItem(Int32
>   k, Object newO, Object parent)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32
>   k, ICollectionView collectionView,
>   Object newValue, Boolean
>   isASubPropertyChange)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.AttachDataItem()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object
>   item)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt
>   attempt)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachOverride(DependencyObject
>   target, DependencyProperty dp)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Attach(DependencyObject
>   target, DependencyProperty dp)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnAttach(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyProperty dp)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata
>   metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean
>   coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType
>   operationType, Boolean isInternal)
>   at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Object value)    at
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object
>   instance, Object value)    at
>   MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember
>   member, Object obj, Object value)
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object
>   inst, XamlMember property, Object
>   value)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.SetValue(Object
>   inst, XamlMember property, Object
>   value)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ApplyPropertyValue(ObjectWriterContext
>   ctx, XamlMember prop, Object value,
>   Boolean onParent)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(ObjectWriterContext
>   ctx)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(ObjectWriterContext
>   ctx)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()
>   at
>   System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader
>   reader)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader
>   xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter
>   xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties,
>   Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo,
>   IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo,
>   IXamlLineInfoConsumer
>   xamlLineInfoConsumer,
>   XamlContextStack`1 stack,
>   IStyleConnector styleConnector)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader
>   xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory
>   writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object
>   rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader
>   xamlReader, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object
>   rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
>   accessLevel, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream
>   stream, ParserContext parserContext,
>   Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object
>   component, Uri resourceLocator)    at
>   OCC600.LogManager.LogViewer.InitializeComponent()
>   in c:\dev\LUT600
>   2.1.1\OCC600\DotNet4\Source\LogManager\LogManager\Views\LogViewer.xaml:line
>   1    at
>   OCC600.LogManager.LogViewer..ctor(LogsViewModel
>   model, LogMessage log) in
>   C:\dev\LUT600
>   2.1.1\OCC600\DotNet4\Source\LogManager\LogManager\Views\LogViewer.xaml.cs:line
>   31    at
>   OCC600.LogManager.Models.LogsViewModel.CreateDataItemDetailsWindow(LogMessage
>   dataItem, Int64 key) in C:\dev\LUT600
>   2.1.1\OCC600\DotNet4\Source\LogManager\LogManager\Models\LogsViewModel.cs:line
>   163    at
>   ControlsLibrary.wpf.GenericViewModel`2.OpenDataItemDetailsWindow(T
>   dataItem, Int64 windowKey, Boolean
>   trackWindow) in C:\dev\LUT600
>   2.1.1\OCC600\DotNet4\Source\Libraries\ControlsLibrary\Utility\GenericViewModel.cs:line
>   163    at
>   OCC600.LogManager.Models.LogsViewModel.OpenLogDetailsWindow(LogMessage
>   log) in C:\dev\LUT600
>   2.1.1\OCC600\DotNet4\Source\LogManager\LogManager\Models\LogsViewModel.cs:line
>   190    at
>   OCC600.LogManager.Models.LogsViewModel.DisplayDetails(IEnumerable
>   data, Boolean trackWindows) in
>   C:\dev\LUT600
>   2.1.1\OCC600\DotNet4\Source\LogManager\LogManager\Models\LogsViewModel.cs:line
>   176    at
>   OCC600.LogManager.LogsView.logDataGrid_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(Object
>   sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) in
>   C:\dev\LUT600
>   2.1.1\OCC600\DotNet4\Source\LogManager\LogManager\Views\LogsView.xaml.cs:line
>   201    at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate
>   handler, Object target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs
>   routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object
>   source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.HandleDoubleClick(Object
>   sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate
>   handler, Object target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs
>   routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object
>   source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs args,
>   RoutedEvent newEvent)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object
>   sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate
>   handler, Object target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs
>   routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object
>   source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs
>   args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs
>   args, Boolean trusted)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs
>   input)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr
>   hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp,
>   RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
>   Int32 y, Int32 wheel)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr
>   wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
>   handled)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr
>   lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr
>   lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object
>   o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) 
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args,
>   Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

The offending line is:

```
<cdic:TextViewer Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

defined in the following context:

```
<Grid Name="dGrid" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Margin="0,5,0,5" >                 
            </Border>
            <cdic:TextViewer Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Row="1"/>            
        </Grid>
```

This exception is thrown during the call to  InitializeComponent() defined in the following constructor:

```
 public LogViewer(LogsViewModel model, LogMessage log)
        {
            this.myKey = log.Key;
            this.DataContext = model;                               
            InitializeComponent();

            dGrid.DataContextChanged += delegate
            {
                if (dGrid.DataContext != null)
                    this.Title = string.Format(LocalizedStrings.LogDetails + ": {0}",
                        (dGrid.DataContext as LogMessage).ToString());
            };

            dGrid.DataContext = log;
        }
```

I do not have this problem in .NET 3.5.  Any ideas on how I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use add an x:Name attribute to my custom control in the XAML, problem goes away.

So,

```
   <cdic:TextViewer x:Name="textViewer" Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

does not throw an exception while:

```
<cdic:TextViewer Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

does.

Answer (score 2):

The line that is throwing the error looks like it comes from a custom control, it could be that the TextViewer control does not like .net 4. If you have access to the source code then I would try to compile/test that control seperately from the rest of your project to isolate the issue.

Comment: Exception is being thrown deep within Microsoft's code as long as I use a binding.